# SharePoint 2010 form Library template and Infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, infopath

I want to update a field in my Forms Document Library.

I’ve created a Forms Library, added a custom column. Then  clicked on advanced > edit template which fires up Infopath. A blank form opens up.
I then add a text control and a submit button on the form. These controls show up in Main data connection..

Under Data tab, I create a Data Connection to the library I wish to be updated (the one I just opened via advanced). In the wizard I select Submit Data, Doc Library. This creates a Secondary Data Source.

Then set an action on the button to set fields value.  However when I click on the tree which brings up the dialog box to select the field(column), all the fields have a lock icon. Anyway I am able to select the field in the Document Library I wish to update and then the value which is the control on the form.

Once published a new item is created in the Form Document Library but the column is not being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting data SharePoint library connection type enables an InfoPath form to submit data as a document to a SharePoint document library. It not submit the fields in the form to library columns.
As a workaround, I suggest you creating a form which use “SharePoint Form Library”, then publish this form with the Text Box control to the form library. Then the text box control value will published to the library column after submitting.

Comment: In InfoPath Form Options > Property Promotion, I added the fields which created the list columns.